# Plural Noun + Are/Is + uncountable noun

Tags: uncountable-nouns, conjugation

I am trying to write a sentence like the following:

> The skills I acquired is/are knowledge in A, B, and C.

However, I know that uncountable nouns such as *knowledge* doesn't go with *are*. Yet, the subject is a plural noun *skills* so *are* seems to be appropriate. Which one is correct?

Comment: You have to use "are". Mismatches in number are not uncommon, cf. _These **results** were really **something** to be proud of_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence you quoted is a shortened version of this: "The skills I acquired **are** knowledge in A, *knowledge in* B, and *knowledge in* C." The second and third occurrences of "knowledge in" may be omitted, but the things acquired are still multiple.